Replace values in a template table with templateProcessor
I have a doc template which contains the following table:

and with php I fill the variable with this line:
$templateProcessor->setValues(array("{key1}" => 59, "{key2}" => 80));

The output I get is the following:

Note that key1 has been replaced twice, while key2 only in the text area and not inside the table. The problem seems to be related to the way the templateProcessor handles tables... Is there any way to make this work?
I also tried just with setValue, getting the same result
$templateProcessor->setValue("{key1}", 59);
$templateProcessor->setValue("{key2}", 80);


Have you looked in https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues to see if anyone raised something similar? I suspect on Stackoverflow you won't get the internals of PHPWord fixed, but you might if you raise a ticket with the project directly (or vote for an existing ticket about the same issue, if it exists).

The solution was to use a clearer syntax in the template, marking all placeholders with ${placeholder} instead of {placeholder}.
This allows a clean:
$templateProcessor->setValues(array("key1" => 59, "key2" => 80));

